# React - Calling a function with an object inside an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, redux, react-redux

I created functions and objects inside it and I'm trying to call this function inside another object I wanted to separate objects inside another function so that the code is easier to read, but I only render one object and not all objects

**JavaScript_Lessons_Objects.js**

```
import {faDotCircle} from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons/faDotCircle";
import React from "react";

const one = "Robby";

function JavaScriptLessonObject() {
    return (
        {
            titleName: "JSON1",
            iconName: faDotCircle,
            description: [
                <span className="yourClass">{one}</span>,
                ` advanced diverted domestic sex repeated bringing you old.`
            ],
        },
            {
                titleName: "JSON2",
                iconName: faDotCircle,
                description: [
                    <span className="yourClass">{one}</span>,
                    ` advanced diverted domestic sex repeated bringing you old.`
                ],
            }
    );
}

export default JavaScriptLessonObject;
```

**lesson-reducer.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import JavaScriptLessonObject from "./Coding_Lessons_Objects/JavaScript_Lessons_Objects";

const ADD_LESSON = "ADD_LESSON";

let initialState = {
    lessonsTitle: [
        JavaScriptLessonObject()
    ],

};

export const lessonReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ADD_LESSON:
            return {
                ...state, lessonsTitle: action.lessonsTitle
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export const getLessons = (lessonsTitle) => ({
    type: ADD_LESSON, lessonsTitle
});
```

**Lesson.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import less from "./css/lesson.module.css";
import "./css/betaLesson.css";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { Navbar } from "../../../Navbar/Navbar";
import { faDotCircle } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons/faDotCircle";

export class Lessons extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            indexDescription: 0,
        }
    }

    render() {
        const listLessons = this.props.lesson.map((item, index) => {
            return (
                <ul key={index}>
                    <li className={less.sidebar_list} onClick={() => {
                        this.setState({ indexDescription: index })
                    }}>
                        <div>
                            <FontAwesomeIcon className={less.item_icon} icon={item.iconName} />
                        </div>

                        <div className={less.titleName}>
                            <p>{item.titleName}</p>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            );
        });

        return (
            <>
                <div className="abc">
                    <Navbar color="blue" bg="tomato" centerFlexNavbarContainer="flex"
                        navbarSearchPage="Search" navbarHomePage="Home" centerHeadlineNavbarColumn="center" />
                    <div className={less.wrapper}>

                        <div className={less.sidebar}>
                            <div>
                                {listLessons}
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div className={less.main_content}>
                            <div className={less.main_inside_content}>
                                <div className={less.header}>
                                    <div>
                                        <h2>JavaScript JSON Reference</h2>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div className={less.info}>
                                    <div className={less.description}>
                                        <p>
                                            {
                                                this.props.lesson[this.state.indexDescription]["description"]
                                            }
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </>
        );
    }
}
```

Instead of getting two objects JSON1 and JSON2, I only get JSON2 https://ibb.co/4KT9qMH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function JavaScriptLessonObject() {
    return (
        [{
            titleName: "JSON1",
            iconName: faDotCircle,
            description: [
                <span className="yourClass">{one}</span>,
                ` advanced diverted domestic sex repeated bringing you old.`
            ],
        },
            {
                titleName: "JSON2",
                iconName: faDotCircle,
                description: [
                    <span className="yourClass">{one}</span>,
                    ` advanced diverted domestic sex repeated bringing you old.`
                ],
            }]
    );
}
```

try returning an array in the function like this ^

```
let initialState = {
    lessonsTitle: JavaScriptLessonObject()

};
```

and calling it in this ^ manner.